# Java, how can I skip individual fields instead of reading the whole row?

Tags: java, csv

Working on an assignment for OOP and I brought it up to my professor and was told we can't skip entire rows of a .tsv file, but just skip the field to not include it in a calculation

I am doing (averages for age, salary, hours worked).  For example if the first row Has "NA" or a decimal in the age field, we have to skip only that field but not the entire row, as that row may have a salary field we can use.

I now understand that I am skipping entire rows with my logic with reader.readLine(), but how do I just  skip a field within the row if it is not useful?

Age is field[3], Salary is field[7], Hours worked is field[58]

My code for my file reader

```
 try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("survey_results_public_subset.tsv"));
            String line;
            String splitBy = "\t";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] field = line.split(splitBy);
                if (field[3].equals("NA") || field[3].contains(".")
                        || !field[5].equals("Yearly") || field[22].equals("NA")
                        || field[7].contains("3E+05") || field[7].contains("1E+05") || field[7].contains("2E+05")
                        || field[7].equals("NA") || field[7].contains("5E+05")
                        || field[7].contains("4E+05") || field[7].contains("6E+05")
                        || field[7].contains("7E+05") || field[7].contains("1E+06")
                        || field[58].contains("NA") || field[58].contains(".")) {

                    reader.readLine();

                } else {

                    int age = Integer.parseInt(field[3]);
                    int salary = Integer.parseInt(field[7]);
                    int hoursWorked = Integer.parseInt(field[58]);
                    System.out.println("Age: " + age + " Salary: " + salary + " Hours: " + hoursWorked + "\n");
                }
            }

        }
```

Example sets of data

```
8   I am a developer by profession  Yes 36  12  Yearly  116000  116000  United States   United States dollar    USD MongoDB MariaDB;MySQL;Redis "Developer, back-end;Developer, desktop or enterprise applications;Developer, game or graphics" "Bachelor’s degree (B.A., B.S., B.Eng., etc.)"  Employed full-time  White or of European descent    Man Remote work options;Opportunities for professional development;Family friendliness  Slightly dissatisfied   "I’m not actively looking, but I am open to new opportunities"  JavaScript  Python;SQL  Unity 3D    Ansible NA  "Confluence;Jira;Github;Slack;Microsoft Teams;Google Suite (Docs, Meet, etc)"   Yes Extremely important Not at all important/not necessary  Curious about other opportunities;Better compensation;Trouble with my direct manager;Trouble with leadership at my company;Better work/life balance;Wanting to work with new technologies;Growth or leadership opportunities    "Read company media, such as employee blogs or company culture videos;Company reviews from third party sites (e.g. Glassdoor, Blind);Personal network - friends or family;Read other media like news articles, founder profiles, etc. about the company"    Once a year Not sure    Yes No  Occasionally: 1-2 days per quarter but less than monthly    Start a free trial;Ask developers I know/work with;Visit developer communities like Stack Overflow;Read ratings or reviews on third party sites like G2Crowd    "Hello, old friend" Stack Overflow (public Q&A for anyone who codes);Stack Overflow Jobs (for job seekers)  Play games;Call a coworker or friend;Visit Stack Overflow;Go for a walk or other physical activity;Watch help / tutorial videos;Do other work and come back later   Linux-based 20 to 99 employees  iOS;Slack Apps and Integrations Docker  I have some influence   Straight / Heterosexual Yes "No, not really"    Less than once per month or monthly Multiple times per day  Easy    Appropriate in length   No  "Computer science, computer engineering, or software engineering"   Django;React.js;Vue.js  Flask   Just as welcome now as I felt last year 39  17  13

41  I am a developer by profession  No  NA  15  Yearly  106000  106000  United States   United States dollar    USD Microsoft SQL Server    Microsoft SQL Server    "Developer, back-end;Developer, front-end;Developer, full-stack"    "Master’s degree (M.A., M.S., M.Eng., MBA, etc.)"   Employed full-time  NA  NA  Remote work options;Financial performance or funding status of the company or organization;Opportunities for professional development   Slightly dissatisfied   "I’m not actively looking, but I am open to new opportunities"  C;C#;Java;SQL   C;C#;Java;SQL   .NET;.NET Core;Node.js  .NET;Hadoop Microsoft Teams Slack;Microsoft Teams;Trello    No  Neutral Very important  Better compensation;Wanting to work with new technologies;Growth or leadership opportunities    "Read company media, such as employee blogs or company culture videos;Company reviews from third party sites (e.g. Glassdoor, Blind);Publicly available financial information (e.g. Crunchbase)"    Once a year No  No  No  Never   Start a free trial;Visit developer communities like Stack Overflow;Read ratings or reviews on third party sites like G2Crowd    "Hello, old friend" Stack Overflow (public Q&A for anyone who codes);Stack Exchange (public Q&A for a variety of topics)    Visit Stack Overflow;Do other work and come back later  Windows 500 to 999 employees    Windows Windows I have some influence   NA  Yes Neutral Daily or almost daily   Daily or almost daily   NA  NA  NA  "Computer science, computer engineering, or software engineering"   Vue.js  ASP.NET;Vue.js  A lot less welcome now than last year   40  25  20
```

Also, is there a better and neater way to skip the fields that are listed as such: 6E+05

EDIT:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] field = line.split(splitBy);
                String ageString = field[3];
                String hoursString = field[58];
                String salaryString = field[7];
                String payfreString = field[5];

                int hours = 0;
                int age = 0;
                int salary = 0;

                if(!ageString.equals("NA") && !ageString.contains(".")){

                     age = Integer.parseInt(ageString);
                    //System.out.print(age + "\t" + "\n");
                }

                 if (!salaryString.equals("NA") && payfreString.equals("Yearly") && !salaryString.contains("E") ) {

                     salary = Integer.parseInt(salaryString);
                    //System.out.println("Salary" + salary + "\n" );
                }

                 if (!hoursString.equals("NA") && !hoursString.contains(".")) {
                      hours = Integer.parseInt(hoursString);
                    // System.out.println("Hours " + hours);
                 }
                System.out.println("Hours: " + hours + " Age "+ age + " Salary " + salary);
                 
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When programming it's always good to build your code in logical steps. Your if statement too complex for what you are doing. Take it in simple steps as you have started.
First get each line as a string (you have done this).

`(line = reader.readLine()) != null`

Then split the line by tab character (you have done this).

`String[] field = line.split(splitBy);`

Then extract the strings you want (you need to do this).

`String ageStr = field[3];`

`String salaryStr = field[7];`

Then validate each string you are interested in, ignoring those which done fit the criteria (you need to do this)

`if(!ageStr.equals("NA")) { //is valid }`

This approach then results in you only doing things with 'valid' elements and any invalid elements are ignored.

Comment: I edit my post to include my newer code.  Thoughts?  

I also can't believe I just didnt just put .contains("E") for salary values that have it.  I swear I over think things.

Comment: I think that is alot better. It makes it alot more readable and easier to understand. Without knowing exactly what kind of quality to be expected I think it is good. You could also look into the use of StringBuilder to construct a string and then print at the end. But at the point it just just superfluous.